# How to create a builder project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have the one `parent` project and two `child-1`/`child-2` projects. On my disk, there all share the same parent directory:

```
/my-project
    /parent
    /child-1
    /child-2
```

For the sake of having a minimal working exception, consider the following `pom.xml`s:

## parent

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

## child-1

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

## child-2

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

## the question

In the `parent` project, I intentionally did not include the following modules definition:

```
<modules>
    <module>child-1</module>
    <module>child-2</module>
</modules>
```

The reason for that is that I want to build the parent independently from the child projects. Whenever the parent project changes, Jenkins will rebuild all child project automatically anyway.

On my develop machine, it would be useful if I could rebuild the whole project. That is, first `parent`, and then `child-1` and `child-2`. I could call `mvn compile` in all 3 directories, but that's quite cumbersome. Note that in the real case, there are much more `child` projects and there are dependencies between them. So I would have to build each `child` project corresponding to their topological sorting in the projects dependency graph.

So I thought about introducing a `builder` project as following:

```
/my-project
    /parent
    /child-1
    /child-2
    /builder
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../parent</module>
        <module>../child-1</module>
        <module>../child-2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Now, when I call `mvn compile` in the `builder` directory, I get:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:child-1:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:child-2:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test:child-1:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/ebbe/my-project/child-1/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:child-1:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test:child-2:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/ebbe/my-project/child-2/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:child-2:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

Why is that? How can this be fixed? Is my idea with this `builder` project possible at all?

Comment: Remove the builder and change the `<modules><module>child-1</module><module>child-2</module><modules>`. For more information check the official [example](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html)

Comment: @Igor The idea is that I do not want to have `modules` declared in the parent, but in a separate builder project. This way, I (and Jenkins) could build the parent independently, without having to have the child projects checked out/present on disk.

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn compile -pl child-1,child-2` from the **parent** directory?

Comment: I am not sure what your suggestion is. The option `-pl` in `parent` will not work, as this is not a module project?